# Is publishing older components and pages mandatory after DD4T 2.0 Upgrade?

Tags: dd4t, sdl-tridion

We have a web application running on DD4T 1.3. The application is running fine, all good. Next.

In a new engagement, we are building a few NEW pages, new Schemas, new Component Templates, new Pages, new page Templates ALL from scratch.

Now, for this new engagement, we are ready to publish everything we now create newly with DD4T 2.0 Templates.

We want existing templates on CMS to use the same old dd4t 1.0. Is it possible?

Overall objective: We don't want to publish 1000's of pages and components we already have on our CMS which are using 1.3 DD4T now. We are ready to publish the newly built pages/components on dd4t 2.0.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to publish all the items after the upgrade to DD4T 2.0 from 1.x, the framework should be able to serialize items even if they are stored in XML format in the broker.

Read more [here.](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/14103/346)

Comment: I think you do have to republish DCPs, because the structure of DCPs changed.

Comment: Depence if you run both applications next to each other or not. If you tweak the controllers to only resolve certain paths and create new content in a new path thats only picked up by DD4T you do not require to republish anything.

Comment: In one of our scenarios, we did republish of DCP will not work older content in XML format and newly published content in JSON format (structure is changed)